# ValueError: Unable to parse string "-" at position 1363

Tags: python, pandas

it seems that the data source I'm pulling from (API) has a weird '-' symbol that isn't recognized when I do str.replace. Here's the code and the library I used. Error occurs on pd.to_numeric. Casting as float returns the same error without the position.

```
Y = xy['QPerf'].str.rstrip('%')
Y = Y.str.replace('-', '-')
Y = pd.to_numeric(Y)
Y = Y.apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0)
print(Y)
```

I have tried `str.encode('UTF-8').str.decode('UTF-8')` but unsurprisingly it doesn't work.

Here is the library code to get your own data to try this on.

```
from finvizfinance.quote import finvizfinance
from finvizfinance.screener.overview import Overview

stock = finvizfinance('TSLA')
stock_fundament = stock.TickerFundament()
qperf = stock_fundament['Perf Quarter']
```

This will return a dataframe.

Comment: It could be a different unicode character that looks similar. Can you pull out an example of your data with this character and then `print(repr(value))` so we can see it too. You could also isolate the character and do `ord(the_character)` to see if its 45 (the ascii dash) or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it was just a nan value so replace wasn't handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always ignore errors and replace with `NaN`s in `pd.to_numeric` using the [`errors='coerce'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3.0/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) parameter. That’s likely what `-` means too, it’s not a number, it’s representing missing data.

```
Y = pd.to_numeric(xy['QPer'].str.rstrip('%'), errors='coerce')
```

This has the downside of also ignoring any other errors, and maybe make you miss formatting errors that you would like to know about.

If you were reading from a csv file, you could use `na_values` to specify that `-` mean `NaN`s. In this context we can use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to replace the `-` with `NaN`s, and then use `to_numeric`:

```
Y = pd.to_numeric(xy['QPer'].str.rstrip('%').mask(xy['QPer'] == '-'))
```

Comment: I think this is a helpful answer. I had misdiagnosed my error, it turns out that the error-producing '-' was coming from NaN's in the dataset- not negative percentage values. So I just used `xy = xy.loc[xy['QPerf'] != '-']` . Thank you for your answer and the additional cases you covered.